# Get Intermediate Activation Layers for a Keras Model in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional Keras model and I'm trying to get a TensorFlow graph that will give me the intermediate activation layers but I don't get the right results the following way:

```python
import skimage.transform as transform
import imageio
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import models

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(540, 960, 3))
layer_dict = {layer.name:layer for layer in conv_base.layers}

image = imageio.imread('/home/john/001000.png')
image = transform.resize(image, (540, 960), mode='constant')
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

#In Keras, I would just do this:
#model = models.Model(inputs=conv_base.input, outputs=layer_dict[layerName])
#prediction = model.predict(image)
#print(np.sum(prediction))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

ans = sess.run(layer_dict['block5_conv2'].output, feed_dict={(conv_base.input): image})
print(np.sum(ans))
```

I'm taking the sums of the result just as a quick comparison.  I think in TensorFlow when I initialize the variables, it resets all the weights because I get a random result every time.  However, it also won't let me run without initializing.  I'm doing this because I want to be able to do this in Go, so I'm trying to do it first in Python with Keras, then Python directly with TensorFlow, then Go with TensorFlow.  I think if I can make it work in TensorFlow, I can save it to a file in Python, then load it in Go.